# Min of same column multiple times

Tags: sql, oracle

First post on this site, so let me know if it is well formulated.

Some context: where I work we have a pick-up counter and we would like to see the **MIN** time stamp of three seperate transactions. Time entered, time of first pick, time shipped are the three variables. It requires me doing the **MIN** of the same column three seperate times with different conditions on each. This is where I am stuck:

```
SELECT CONTROL_NUMBER, MIN(START_TRAN_TIME) AS START_T, 
       MIN(START_TRAN_TIME) AS PICK_T, 
       MIN(START_TRAN_TIME) AS SHIP_T
FROM T_TRAN_LOG
WHERE  WH_ID = 'W376' ....
```

The time stamp is dictated by the transaction type (TRAN_TYPE) variable. 
- The START_T column is where the TRAN_TYPE is equal to '961'
- The PICK_T column is where the tran_type is equal to '306'
- The SHIP_T column is where the tran_type is equal to '340'

```
tran type         start_tran_time
   340             6/18/2018 8:14
   306             6/18/2018 8:10
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here, I have been self learning a lot of SQL, so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: `MIN(CASE WHEN TRAN_TYPE =  '961' THEN START_TRAN_TIME END) AS START_T` similarly for othr two column

Comment: You'll probably end up with case expressions in your min()'s, to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `case/when`and `min`

```
select
  CONTROL_NUMBER, 
  Min(case when tran_type = '961' then START_TRAN_TIME else null end) AS START_T, 
  Min(case when tran_type = '306' then START_TRAN_TIME else null end) AS PICK_T, 
  Min(case when tran_type = '340' then START_TRAN_TIME else null end) AS SHIP_T, 
from
  T_TRAN_LOG
where
  WH_ID = 'W376' 
Group by
  CONTROL_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thank you! I switched it to null and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use case when to select the different tran types:

```
SELECT CONTROL_NUMBER, 
       Min(case when tran_type = '961' then START_TRAN_TIME else null end) AS START_T, 
       Min(case when tran_type = '306' then START_TRAN_TIME else null end) AS PICK_T, 
       Min(case when tran_type = '340' then START_TRAN_TIME else null end) AS SHIP_T, 
FROM T_TRAN_LOG
WHERE  WH_ID = 'W376' 
Group by CONTROL_NUMBER
```

Comment: The case expressions should be inside the min()'s. You're doing the opposite.

Comment: Thank you very much for the rapid response! The only message I get now is inconsistent data types. It says it wants a Date format and not a number format. But I will flag this as an answer!

Comment: with `else 0` your result will be `0` - you need `else null`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like that:

```
    SELECT CONTROL_NUMBER 
from T_TRAN_LOG pivot
(
    MIN(START_TRAN_TIME) for PICK_T 
                                in('961' as "START_T",
                                '306' as "PICK_T" ,
                                '340' as "SHIP_T")
                                )
where WH_ID = 'W376' ...
```

I don't know if it is answer to your question, since i don't have full data.